# Sqlite Avoid Duplicates Using Insert, Executemany and list of Tuples

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an existing Sqlite table containing qualification data for students, the code periodically checks for new qualifications obtained and inserts them into the table.  This causes duplicates.

```
    def insertQualificationData(data):

        # Run execute many command to insert data
        self.cursor.executemany(
            """
                INSERT INTO qualification  (
                    qualificationperson,
                    type,
                    secondaryreference,
                    reference,
                    name,
                    pass,
                    start,
                    qualificationband,
                    grade,
                    time_stamp
                ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
            """, data
        )
```

The 'data' variable is a list of tuples. Eg:

```
('209000010111327', 'WLC', 'G0W915', 'Certificate', 'Child Care and Education', 'P', '12/07/2001', 'PASS', 'Pass', 1648018935)
```

I want to prevent 'duplicate' values being inserted into the qualifications table, by 'duplicate' I mean if a row matches the *qualificationperson, reference, name & pass* columns it should not insert.

I have seen other answers doing a similar thing but with named columns from a second table, I am struggling with replicating this using a list of tuples and executemany()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a unique index on those columns:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS QData ON qualification (qualificationperson, reference, name, pass)
```

and then use an [`INSERT OR IGNORE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) statement so that a failure of one value to insert does not cause the entire `executemany` to fail:

```sql
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO qualification (...)
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for taking the time to help me with my issue.  Can I ask, this "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX" command, is that done at the point of table creation or is it done subsequently?

Comment: @cwfmoore you would ideally do that when you create the table. But it can be done at any time after table creation too; except that if there is already any duplicate data in the  table the command will fail. In that situation you will need to remove the duplicate data prior to running the create index command.

Comment: @cwfmoore how are you going with this? do you need more assistance?

Comment: It worked fine on one table, but I cant seem to replicate it on a second table.
image: [link]https://imgur.com/dAk8Rxv 
image: [link]https://imgur.com/RVAmsrE

Comment: Ok, i figured out that the index name (QData) in your example must also be unique?  Changing the name of this worked for me.

Comment: @cwfmoore Yes, all indexes in a database must have unique names.